# ¿Por qué mi EventListener se activa apenas dando clic al cuadro de texto para ingresar el input?

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript, quiero hacer un programa que me console.log's dependiendo del día de la semana que ingrese en el input después de darle al botón "check".

En mi HTML añadí un input de tipo texto dentro de un form, seguido del elemento form (como hermano) añadí su respectivo botón con contenido textual claro, le puse "check!"

En JavaScript añadí los smurfs al inicio, seguido de la declaración de la función y los conecté por medio del segundo parámetro del método .addEventListener para que tengan coherencia.

El fallo aquí es que me lanza el console.log apenas dando clic en el input sin nisiquiera añadir nada en él.

```js
document.querySelector('#buscador').addEventListener('click', funcionChingona)

function funcionChingona() {

    const day = document.querySelector('#buscador').value

    if(day === "lunes" || day === "martes" || day === "miercoles" || day === "jueves" || day === "viernes"){
        console.log("TIENES CLASES!")
    }
    else if(day === "sabado" || day === "domingo"){
        console.log("FIN DE SEMANA!")
    }
    else{
        console.log("ABURRIDO")
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: linear-gradient(black, white);
    background: no-repeat fixed;
}

.titulo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


.firma{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>DÍA DE LA SEMANA</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>
            Ingresa el día de la semana:
        </h1>
    </div>
    <form>
        <label for="buscador"> BUSCADOR:   </label>
        <input type="text" id="buscador" placeholder="Ingrésalo... ">
    </form>
    <button id="buscador" type="button" name="button">Check! </button>
    <div class="firma">
        <p>Hecho por Alexis Zárate</p>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que estaba pensando es que tal vez el JavaScript tenga el error en el smurf, pero tengo entendio que los parámetros son correctos, primero

Comment: Hola zaraterdz, el problema es que tienes varios item con **id="buscador"**, eso proboca comportamientos inesperados, los **id** deben ser únicos, deja como **id="buscador";** al botón check.

Comment: gracias, me solucionaste el problema Marce Puente

Comment: Un placer ayudarte.

Comment: Entonces no uses el evento clic. Mejor usa uno que se ejecute al modificar el contenido del input.

Comment: Y cuál sería ese @Mateo ?

Comment: El evento [**change**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

Answer (score 0):

Tienes los dos id en "buscador".. por eso al dar el clic en el placeholder estas llamando tambien a la funcion que tambien tiene como id a "buscador".. Una solucion es cambiar uno de los dos id a "ingreso" o "dia" o como quieras llamarlo.. saludos